# Iterate over a list of lists of dictionaries

Tags: python

I need to return a specific value from every dictionary. In this case, I need to return the action performed by the antivirus, whose id is either id:5 or id:6. The action is either File Cleaned or Quarantine Successfully. Another problem is that the lists do not have the same length. Most have 6 dictionaries in them, but sometimes you can find a list with 1 dict or even 8 dicts.

Here is the list:

```
data = [
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "detection_name",
            "field": "malName",
            "value": "HKTL_AMMYYADMIN",
            "provenance": [
                "Alert"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "type": "file_sha1",
            "field": "fileHash",
            "value": "",
            "provenance": [
                "Alert"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "type": "filename",
            "field": "fileName",
            "value": "D:\\PAMH\\DATA\\LABORTATORY\\AMMYY_Admin.exe",
            "provenance": [
                "Alert"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "type": "fullpath",
            "field": "fullPath",
            "value": "D:\\PAMH\\DATA\\LABORTATORY\\AMMYY_Admin.exe",
            "provenance": [
                "Alert"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "type": "text",
            "field": "actResult",
            "value": "File cleaned",
            "provenance": [
                "Alert"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "type": "text",
            "field": "scanType",
            "value": "Real-time Scan",
            "provenance": [
                "Alert"
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "command_line",
            "field": "objectCmd",
            "value": "c:\\SW\\nmap\\nmap.exe  -sS -P0 92.168.155.83 -p 22",
            "provenance": [
                "Alert"
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "detection_name",
            "field": "malName",
            "value": "HackTool.Win32.PortScan.SWO",
            "provenance": [
                "Alert"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "type": "file_sha1",
            "field": "fileHash",
            "value": "",
            "provenance": [
                "Alert"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "type": "filename",
            "field": "fileName",
            "value": "E:\\EXCHANGE\\John Smith\\Documents\\Advanced_Port_Scanner_2.5.3869.exe",
           "provenance": [
                "Alert"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "type": "filename",
            "field": "fileName",
            "value": "H:\\home\\john.smith\\Documents\\Advanced_Port_Scanner_2.5.3869.exe",
            "provenance": [
                "Alert"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "type": "fullpath",
            "field": "fullPath",
            "value": "H:\\home\\john.smith\\Documents\\Advanced_Port_Scanner_2.5.3869.exe",
            "provenance": [
                "Alert"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "type": "text",
            "field": "actResult",
            "value": "File cleaned",
            "provenance": [
                "Alert"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "type": "text",
            "field": "actResult",
            "value": "File cleaned",
            "provenance": [
                "Alert"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "type": "text",
            "field": "scanType",
            "value": "Scheduled Scan",
            "provenance": [
                "Alert"
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

I'm able to return values from a list of dicts, but so far everything I tried with a list of lists of dicts hasn't worked.

Expected Output:

```
"File cleaned", "-", "File cleaned"
```

Comment: You could [flatten the list first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists), and then you have a list of dicts.

Comment: "I'm able to return values from a list of dicts..." You have the right idea by solving a simpler problem. I recommend that you put that code into a function. Then you can use that function to solve the bigger problem. If you still need help with that, please show the code that you have writen so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a recursive generator that will drill down nested lists to pick the dictionaries of interest:

```
def getActions(D,ids):
    if isinstance(D,dict):
        if D["id"] in ids and D["field"] == "actResult":
            yield D["value"]
    else:
        for d in D:
            yield from getActions(d,ids)

print(*getActions(data,{5,6}),sep=" - ")

File cleaned - File cleaned
```

Comment: Thank you. This works great. It's outside the scope of my knowledge though. I need to take a look at generators more in depth. In the meantime, I need the output to be in form of a list. Despite my tinkering with it, I was not able to do it. How can I have a list in the end?

Comment: `list(getActions(data,{5,6}))`

Comment: Hey, so I'm having an issue with the recursion script. When I run in in small controlled example, such as the one I provided in the question, it works perfectly. But when I make a call to the server, I get "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object" since there are too many objects. Any way around it?

Comment: You either have a very deeply nested structure (hundreds of levels deep) or there is one of the nested list that references itself or one of its containers at a higher level

Comment: Mind if I share the logfile?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a flat list based on an existing 2D list. Here is example using List Comprehension

```py
flatten_list = [item['value'] for sublist in data for item in sublist]
print(flatten_list)
```

Comment: Thank you. While this works in some way, it still doesn't produce the exact output I need. It does flatten all items, but then it's impossible to tell which ones I need.